# Does Webpack DefinePlugin support variables or only constants?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I tries to pass an array to *[DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)* . This array is declared globally and filled in by an another plugin (*[DirectoryTreePlugi](https://github.com/skipjack/directory-tree-webpack-plugin)*, *enhance* method). But a browser's debuggers shows what the array is empty.

If I assign some values to the array once I declare it the debugger shows that values. It seems like *DefinePlugin* is called earlier than *DirectoryTreePlugin*, but the order of plugins in Webpack config file is *DirectoryTreePlugin* and then *DefinePlugin*.

Comment: did you stringified the array? They run in order, but the result of the computation from DirectoryTreePlugin should be taking longer, which led to the next plugin be applied anyways.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Compiler.js#L432

Comment: Yes, I use JSON. stringify()

Comment: @MatheusSilva Did I understand you correctly? Plugins run in order, but the next starts not waiting while the previous ends up its computations. If yes, is it a way to sync plugins in described manner?

Comment: "but the next starts not waiting while the previous ends up its computations" - yes.  
" If yes, is it a way to sync plugins in described manner?" - no. See the code that i showed you in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) supports both variales and constants. Thanks to @MatheusSilva pointing me on my misunderstanding about the order of Webpack plugin execution.

I solved my task in the following way.

For doing its job *[DirectoryTreePlugin](https://github.com/skipjack/directory-tree-webpack-plugin)* uses the [directory-tree](https://github.com/mihneadb/node-directory-tree) library. So I just [imported it](https://github.com/mihneadb/node-directory-tree#usage) in Webpack config file, filled in my array in *dirTree* callback and pass it (array) to *DefinePlugin*.